# On button click user should be navigated to the New action of an object

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I have been working on creating a new list view All Vendors(for Custom Vendor Object).
Once that is done, I am trying to create a new lightning component, where I create a button named Add new Vendor.
On button click, user should be navigated to the New action of the Vendor object.

Trying to Create another button called as View Vendors
On clicking this button, user should see the list view you created above in the custom lightning component. Trying to Use lightning:listview tab for this.

Please Any one Help.I am not able to do it as I am new to lightning

Comment: Hi Krishna, if you are looking for good advice,  you should add some information on the exact situation where you need this. If you are looking for someone who implements an Aura component for you, this website is not the right place. It's all about precise questions and answers here. Maybe you want to add information to your question?!

Comment: Hi Hove, When I click the vendors (Custom Object) tab in Sales Application, Two buttons (Add New Vendor & View Vendors) should appear (Which I did). now, If I click the a Add new Vendor button , I need to land on Custom aura component page that I developed.

Comment: And when I click the second button (View Vendor), List view of vendors has be populated on the same page

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you can do to solve your issue.

1. Create an Aura component for showing your 2 buttons.
2. On click of Button 1 Add New Vendor Call your child Aura Component.
3. On click of Button 2 View Vendors --> Query on ListView Object with filter SobjectType = 'Vendors__c' to get all the list views in your Org for the Custom Object.
4. On Selecting the list view you can query and fetch the records from Salesforce according to the list view filters.

Let me know if you have a different ask.

Comment: Thank You. That Would Help